# rvmsudo vs sudo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, sudo

I just moved to RVM.

sudo bundle install gives me and error:-

```
 sudo bundle install
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:900:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1276:in `gem'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bundle:18:in `<main>'
```

and

```
rvmsudo bundle install
```

works like a charm. Whats the difference. Whats going on behind the screen. Can anybody explain..

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`sudo` starts a new subshell that does not contain environment variables.
`rvmsudo` passes on any environment variables that RVM set up to get you to the correct Ruby. This includes the `$PATH` as well has `$GEM_HOME`, `$GEM_PATH` and `$BUNDLE_PATH` variables.

https://rvm.io/integration/sudo