# Getting rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I previously installed rails with the preinstalled ruby that comes with mac. I have recently installed ruby through rvm.

I  then did

```
  rails -v
```

and got the following error

```
 kingsosina$ rails -v
 /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find      'railties' (>= 0) among 5 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
```

What has gone wrong here? Do I need to gem install rails again?

my lastest output

```
 kingsosina$ which ruby
 /Users/kingsosina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
 kingsosina$ which rails
 /Users/kingsosina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rails
 kingsosina$ which gem
 /Users/kingsosina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/gem
 kingsosina$
```

Does everything seem ok? and how does terminal know to reference this version of ruby instead of the pre-installed version on the mac, when i do ruby -v?

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, the paths shown in your error output indicate that you're still referencing the OSX version of ruby.  You'll want to enter the directory and type

```
rvm use X.X.X-pXXX
```

where X.X.X-pXXX is the ruby version that you want rvm to use.  You can also add a file called .ruby-version with X.X.X-pXXX in it and rvm and other ruby version managers will switch to the appropriate version for you.  Adding a .ruby-gemset file will also switch to the appropriate set of gems.

Finally, you'll need to make sure that the gems are installed in the rvm ruby/gemset combination.  Putting that all together, to get started with the latest ruby and latest rails gem you would...

```
rvm install 2.0.0
rvm use 2.0.0
rvm gemset use --create my-project-gems
gem install rails
```

Comment: Hi. did rvm install and my terminal says it already installed. i then did **which rails** and the output is **kingsosina$ which rails
/Users/kingsosina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rails**

Comment: If that's the case then yes, I'd reinstall rails in this environment.

Comment: what `which rails` says is that `rails` is in `PATH`, but the error says that something is wrong, either `GEM_HOME` was not set or the `rails` shebang is broken, you can check: `echo $GEM_HOME` and `head $(which rails)`

Comment: @AndyV @mpapis does this look correct? I managed to get `ruby -v`, `rails -v` and `gem -v` to work accordingly
`kingsosina$ which ruby
 /Users/kingsosina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
 kingsosina$ which rails
 /Users/kingsosina/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/rails
 kingsosina$ which gem
 /Users/kingsosina/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/gem
 kingsosina$`

Comment: Yes, those look like they're properly responding out of rvm rather than system ruby.

Comment: just `which gem rails` does not answer all question, check: `echo $GEM_HOME` and `head $(which rails)`

Answer (score -1):

Did you install newer version of ruby along with the rvm install? Do `rvm list` to find out what rubies your have installed. Then do `rvm use <ruby-version-here>` to select a ruby with rvm. Then you need to `gem install rails` again because its a new ruby. If you get a permission denied error trying to install gems try `rvmsudo gem install rails`.

Comment: Hey. I don't think I did this **curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable** Should I do **rvm install 2.0.0**?

Comment: Yes, install ruby 2.0.0. That is preferred. After you install 2.0.0 try following my suggestion and if it doesn't work post any errors you get.

Comment: downwoted because of the `rvmsudo` it is not needed and can only mess up things.

Comment: I'd like to learn why, can you explain or provide sources? I use it because it works and sudo does not. According to this answer, it's pretty legit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817555/rvmsudo-vs-sudo