# `mkdir': Permission denied (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, wireshark, pcap

i'm trying to open a pcap file but a get this error

I did `deniel@ubuntu:~/Sites Ruby on Rails/helloWorld$ pcap_tools out.pcap`

I got

`/home/deniel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in 'mkdir':Permission denied - /home/deniel/.wireshark/profiles (Errno::EACCES)`

im using this pcap_tools gem from https://github.com/bpaquet/pcap_tools

any idea please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works with rvmsudo pcap_tools out.pcap

Here is an explanation
[rvmsudo vs sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817555/rvmsudo-vs-sudo)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pcap_tools out.pcap
```

Sudo is short for

Sudo = `Super user do command_name`

Are you trying to sniff the internets?

Comment: Im trying to read pcap file, i opened the file using `rvmsudo pcap_tools out.pcap`. Thanks!