# rake not possible on GCE - permission error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm logged into the GCE console and copied my rails app onto the server (tried both var/www and my home directory just to be sure). Connected via gcloud auth login and gcloud compute ssh to my instance as the same user that is owning the project.

Once I'm in the rails directory:
-bundle install works
- rake comes up with this error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `mkdir': Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/bcrypt-3.1.7 (Errno::EACCES)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:250:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `reverse_each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:222:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/fileutils.rb:208:in `mkdir_p'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:210:in `write_gem_make_out'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:132:in `build_error'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:171:in `rescue in build_extension'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:156:in `build_extension'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1436:in `block in build_extensions'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:45:in `use_ui'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1434:in `build_extensions'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb:60:in `build_extensions'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:56:in `contains_requirable_file?'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:925:in `block in find_inactive_by_path'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:924:in `find_inactive_by_path'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:185:in `try_activate'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:9:in `<main>'
```

When I try sudo rake:

```
sudo: rake: command not found
```

any ideas? I'm totally lost with this, cant find any place to set permissions or something similar.

Comment: PATH variable as root is not the same as your user’s one.

Can you try to run it using the full path or with `sudo $(which rake)`? Please, let me know if that solves your issue.

Comment: I've noticed that using the full path does not help either:

    my_user_name@rubystackbox-d844:~/sites/www/site1$ sudo /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/rake db:setup

    /usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Please try this instead:

```
$ rvmsudo rake ...
```

Plase see also:
[rvmsudo vs sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817555/rvmsudo-vs-sudo)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/
```

Rake can then be run without issues.