# RVM says it is using 2.7.3, but ubuntu says i am on 2.7.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Using Ubuntu, I ran the command

```
rvm use 2.7.3
```

I then ran

```
sudo rake db:create
```

and was greeted by the error

```
Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.3
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I have been battling with this for hours and have no idea how to proceed

Comment: @casper Thanks. I was doing that because it said I did not have admin privileges, but I see now that it was referring to my sql user.

Comment: Check ruby -v vs sudo ruby -v

Answer (score 1):

The `$PATH` variable when using `sudo` is not the same as the `$PATH` for your non-sudo user. Because RVM works by modifying `$PATH`, the RVM modifications are lost when you invoke `sudo`. That's why RVM stops working with `sudo`.

If you really need to run something as root using RVM, then you can try it with `rvmsudo` instead.

You can read more here:
[rvmsudo vs sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817555/rvmsudo-vs-sudo)

Also check the manual for `rvmsudo`:
https://rvm.io/integration/sudo

However in your case it's better to adjust access to the database, so that root privileges are not needed for Rails to connect to the DB.